# Laravel: Best way to load models from a child that have many to many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a project where I have the following models and relationships:
[image]

The project have many scenarios(one to many) and the scenarios can have multiple OP Tags(many to many).

I display all the projects on an index page and I have a new request to display all the OP Tags that are part of a project. The unique ones(and in reverse order) because multiple scenarios from the same project can have a relationship with the same OP Tag.

So I wrote this method:

```
        $opTags = collect();

        $project->scenarios->each(function ($scenario) use ($opTags) {
            $scenario->opTags->each(static function ($opTag) use ($opTags) {
                $opTags = $opTags->push($opTag);
            });
        });

        $opTags = $opTags->unique('name')->reverse();
```

But I was thinking that maybe there is a more efficient method? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently using is in fact inefficient as it will create an `n + 1` query problem, unless the relations are already eager loaded. So adding something like this above what you wrote should solve that.

```php
$project->load('scenarios.opTags,name');
```

Also you could write this the other way around like so:

```php
$opTags = OpTag::query()
    ->whereHas('scenarios', function (Builder $query) use ($project) {
        $query->whereRelation('project', 'id', $project->id);
    })
    ->select('name')
    ->distinct()
    ->get();
```